# What is the diffrence between a concurrent tcp client server program and an iterative one?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I want to learn how to write a concurrent TCP client server in C but I can't understand the diffrence between an iterative server-client programm and a concurrent one. On the internet I could not find much information. I look over the TCP client server implementation in C from the site www.geeksforgeeks.org but I think this is an iterative example. How could I make it concurrent?

TCP Server:

```
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr 

// Function designed for chat between client and server. 
void func(int sockfd) 
{ 
char buff[MAX]; 
int n; 
// infinite loop for chat 
for (;;) { 
    bzero(buff, MAX); 

    // read the message from client and copy it in buffer 
    read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
    // print buffer which contains the client contents 
    printf("From client: %s\t To client : ", buff); 
    bzero(buff, MAX); 
    n = 0; 
    // copy server message in the buffer 
    while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n') 
        ; 

    // and send that buffer to client 
    write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 

    // if msg contains "Exit" then server exit and chat ended. 
    if (strncmp("exit", buff, 4) == 0) { 
        printf("Server Exit...\n"); 
        break; 
       } 
    } 
 } 

// Driver function 
int main() 
{ 
int sockfd, connfd, len; 
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 

// socket create and verification 
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if (sockfd == -1) { 
    printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else
    printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

// assign IP, PORT 
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

// Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification 
if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) { 
    printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else
    printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 

// Now server is ready to listen and verification 
if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) { 
    printf("Listen failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else
    printf("Server listening..\n"); 
len = sizeof(cli); 

// Accept the data packet from client and verification 
connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len); 
if (connfd < 0) { 
    printf("server acccept failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else
    printf("server acccept the client...\n"); 

// Function for chatting between client and server 
func(connfd); 

// After chatting close the socket 
close(sockfd); 
}
```

TCP Client:

```
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr 
void func(int sockfd) 
{ 
char buff[MAX]; 
int n; 
for (;;) { 
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff)); 
    printf("Enter the string : "); 
    n = 0; 
    while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n') 
        ; 
    write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff)); 
    read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
    printf("From Server : %s", buff); 
    if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0) { 
        printf("Client Exit...\n"); 
        break; 
      } 
    } 
  } 

int main() 
{ 
int sockfd, connfd; 
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 

// socket create and varification 
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if (sockfd == -1) { 
    printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else
    printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

// assign IP, PORT 
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

// connect the client socket to server socket 
if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) { 
    printf("connection with the server failed...\n"); 
    exit(0); 
} 
else
    printf("connected to the server..\n"); 

// function for chat 
func(sockfd); 

// close the socket 
close(sockfd); 
}
```

Comment: `iterative` - one main loop with `accept` which serves a single connection one after another (ie. iterative). 'concurrent' - one main loop with a accept - on each `accept` a thread is created to handle only that connection, then the main get's back to `accept` and the threads handles "concurrently" the connection. It's not an easy job to write an abstraction and rewrite the program from one approach to another. Create proper layers, allocate memory for threads, use `pthread_create` to dispatch threads to work, remember to call `pthread_detach`.

Comment: Well, they are both wrong. You ignore the return value from `read()` and `write()`. Instead, you assume strings to be transmitted. And, sending `sizeof buff` chunks does send alot of nuls.`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, an iterative server will treat each connection sequentially. In your posted example, if you run the server(after ignoring a bunch of warnings), you can only connect one client. A second client will successfully connect the server, but the server will never respond to it. Only the first client will send messages and get responses.
A concurrent implementation would treat both clients in parallel and would be able to get messages from both. I can think of 3 ways to do this, but one is not recommended:

- As suggested in the comments, put the accept call in a loop. It will block until someone connects. When someone connects, you spawn a thread and give it all the information you need to communicate with the client, the file descriptor(`sockfd`) should suffice for a simple example. After that the thread could execute your `func`, for this thread will only know of one client, but the main loop will block of `accept` again, waiting for another connection. [I found this example on google](https://gist.github.com/oleksiiBobko/43d33b3c25c03bcc9b2b).
- Using POSIX system call [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)(or it's alternatives `poll` and `epoll`), you can monitor a list of sockets for activity. If any of the monitored sockets has activity, a `read` or `accept` to it won`t block, and then you treat these sockets. If the server file descriptor has activity, it means a new client connected, you should store the client file descriptor somewhere, and start passing it to select as well. If a client file descriptor has activity, you handle their messages like before. This way requires no thread, everything is handled on the main routine and may have advantages depending on your use-case
  I found these two examples on google: [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html) and [here](https://github.com/SoleSensei/simple-tcp-chat/blob/master/prj/chat/server.c)
- This way is not recommended: Make your server socket non-blocking with `fcntl`. This way, accept won't block, instead, it will immediately return signaling an error `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`. You can then repeatedly call accept on your main loop, most times it will return an error, but the ones that do not will signal a new client connected. When a client connects, you make its file descriptor non-blocking as well, and store it somewhere. On your main routine, for each client socket you will try a `read` on them, but if no new information is available, it returns an error as well. If something is available, you treat it like before. This has the disadvantage of always demanding 100% CPU utilization. You can insert a delay on the loop, but it will increase additional unnecessary latency. You should not do this.